# How to return a dictionary using field function in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I got an error in my field function.
In my function, I want to return a float value from my variable `total`. And I already searched it and I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628039/valueerror-dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-length-1-2-is-required) but still I don't understand the explanation.
Here's my error.

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Here is my code.

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('total_eec', 'total_tec')
def _consumption_actual_value(self):
    res = {}
    total = 0.0
    for i in self:
        total = i.total_eec + i.total_tec
        res[i.id] = total
    return res

_columns = {'consumption_actual': fields.function(_consumption_actual_value, string='Consumption (kWh) Actual'), # TEC + EEC}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed up both api, you have declared field with old api and function written in new api. You should try following.

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('total_eec', 'total_tec')
def _consumption_actual_value(self):
    for i in self:
        total = i.total_eec + i.total_tec
        i.consumption_actual = total or 0.0


consumption_actual = fields.Float(compute=_consumption_actual_value, string='Consumption (kWh) Actual')
```