# Updating dict with multiple keys but empty values

Tags: python

I know discussions exist for this error [ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628039/valueerror-dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-length-1-2-is-required) but it seem not to apply to my situation. I am trying to add a maximum of 2 elements to a dict containing multiple keys with no values (empty) but I get the error. Here is what I have:

```
    df = [(1, 0, 0) (2, 0, 0) (3, 1, 2) (4, 0, 0) (5, 3, 4)]
    points = set((i[0] for i in df if 0 in i))
    n = {key:[] for key in points}
    for i in n:
        length = len(n[i])
        for length in range(0, 2):
            b = ["1", "0", "1"] 
            n.update(random.choice(b))
            print(n)
```

I run this and I get the error :ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required. Thank you

Comment: Can you gives us an example value for `points` that can be used to run your code, and debug your error, without having access to your `df` object?

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `update` on the dict, `n`, not on the set `n[i]`. The `update` method on dicts requires either a dict, or a sequence of key-value pairs, not just a sequence of individual values. The `update` method on sets takes a sequence of individual values. And, more importantly, the set is what you wanted to update.

Comment: Oh I forgot. I just updated my question. Thank you for reminder

Comment: The next problem is that `n[i].update(…)` asks it to add every member of a sequence, but you're only giving it a single value. That happens not to be an error, because a single-character string is actually a sequence of one single-character string, but it's confusing.

Comment: Oh, wait a sec… each `n[i]` is a list, not a set. Lists don't have `update` in the first place, they have `extend`. But at any rate, you're trying to add one value, not a sequence, so you want `n[i].append(…)`.

Comment: okay but b contains elements in the list which I want to be chosen at random and added as values to the dict. I want each key in the dict to have 2 values selected randomly from b.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem i that `n.update(…)` tries to update the dictionary, not the current value in the dictionary. It expects to be given a sequence of key-value pairs, and you're not giving it that, you're giving it a single value. Hence the exception.

But anyway, you want to modify `n[i]`, not `n`.

Since each `n[i]` is a list, and what you want to do is append a new value to that list, just call `n[i].append(…)` instead of `n.update(…)`.

Put into context:

```
for i in n:
    length = len(n[i])
    for length in range(0, 2):
        b = ["1", "0", "1"] 
        n[i].append(random.choice(b))
        print(n)
```

If you run this, you will see that each key ends up with a list of exactly two values; about two thirds of those values are the string `'1'` and the rest are the string `'0'`. It also prints out a whole bunch of stuff. So I'm guessing this still isn't exactly what you want, but it does solve the problem you were asking about, and should be enough to get you to the next step.

Comment: Wow thank you much. That solved my problem. I just got too stressed I guess. I appreciate

Comment: @jackpetes When I get stressed out with some code that really ought to work and the computer is just being stupid (which is usually not true, usually it's me being stupid… but either way…), I take a break and go think about something else for at least 15 minutes. If the answer isn't obvious after that, at least I'm not as stressed anymore. :)

Comment: True I should have done that. Thank you for the advice and help